# escape a list with an element with '\xae' and print the results

Tags: python, list

I got a list `L = [u'steve', u'micheal', u'pedro\xae']`

when I tried to read it, I got an error, I believe it has something to do with the '\xae'

```
>>> L = [u'steve', u'micheal', u'pedro\xae']
>>>
>>> for n in L:
...     print n
...
steve
micheal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Any idea how to escape the caracter?

The output desired so the reading will be very simple is :

```
L= ['steve', 'micheal', 'pedro']
```

Thanks!

Comment: See http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

Comment: Thank you Martijn!  @Martinho! I believe you are using xp or vista OS. it's not working on my ubunto machine. thank you very much!!

Comment: @mongotop: On your Ubuntu machine, what do `echo $LC_CTYPE`, `echo $LANG`, and `locale` say? And what Ubuntu version do you have? Because I thought that at least recent versions will always give you a utf8 locale (unless you go out of your way to change it, of course). [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) looks like I might be useful. (I just found it in a quick google and skimmed it over, so apologies if it's not useful…)

Comment: This is the output of Local:
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: OK, that's your problem. The `C` locale is the generic, ASCII-only locale that you get if you haven't set anything else. So Python is going to encode anything to 'ascii' to fit your locale. Does `locale -a` include something like `en-US.UTF-8`? If so, you should be able to select that as your default locale somewhere in the Ubuntu system settings GUI stuff. If not… you may need to install stuff or upgrade or something, I'm not sure.

Comment: My ubunto version: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.10
Release:        9.10
Codename:       karmic

Comment: you are correct:  local -a get me this output : `
`C`
`POSIX`
`en_US`
`en_US.utf8`

Comment: @mongotop: I don't have an Ubuntu that old lying around… but it looks like in 10.04 it was similar: `en_US.utf8` installed, but `C` selected by default, and changing it in the System Settings GUI doesn't seem to have any effect. But using the `update-locale` tool works (you need to log in again).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a cheap solution

```
print n.encode('ascii','backslashreplace')
```

or

```
print n.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

but better to look at Martijn Pieters link and fix the encoding ... or you will likely have more problems elsewhere in your program

Comment: Thanks a lot Jortan for chime in!!! I got the same error : `
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
`

Comment: +1, since the OP specifically asked for the "cheap solution" of just ignoring the non-ascii characters, and this is exactly what he needs for that.