# Python3 compare the output print

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a web page and print the text. But, I find some errors in print function when I compare the result of print function.

Compare the output of two print functions, some content is omitted when add a line number parameter in first print function.

My platform:
**win7 32bit, Python3.5, MyCharm5.0**

The code is:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseBoardLink = 'https://bbs.ustc.edu.cn/cgi/'

def assayArticle(link):
    fullLink = baseBoardLink + link
    response = requests.get(fullLink)
    html = response.text

    bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    content = bsobj.find('div', {'class': 'post_text'}).get_text()
    print('bytes show:', bytes(content, encoding='utf-8'))
    lines = re.findall(re.compile('\n[^\n]*'), content)


    for line in range(len(lines)):
        print('%d' % line, lines[line], end='')

    print('*' * 50)

    for line in range(len(lines)):
        print(lines[line], end='')

startLink = '/bbscon?bn=CS&fn=M5787A417&num=8086'
assayArticle(startLink)
```

**Here is the result:**

The output of the first print:

[image: The output of the first print]

The output of the second print:

[image: The output of the second print]

I have this error for a few days now, and can't find a solution for it.

Comment: Have you checked out this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470483/printing-non-ascii-characters-in-python-3 I don't know Chinese, but when I run your code and print to a file and open it using nano, the version with line number displays everything. Also, note that your line numbers actually appear at the end of the previous line :) other than that, I think it's just the windows command line that cannot display Chinese character. Try printing to a text file and open with nano or vim or perhaps even notepad?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.when i print to a text, the output has no errors. But in mycharm console, the output is like the output of first print. So, as you say, maybe it's the error of windows command line.@Tuan333